# Uncaught property of undefined using method chaining

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

With below code I got error of property undefined, I don't know what is wrong. I do console.log(navList) in the render it has value. I do if(!navList) return null I still got the same error, I suspect it has todo with chaining.

```
render(){
const navList = [
            {
                path: '/boss',
                text: 'Boss',
                icon: 'boss',
                title: 'Boss List',
                component: Talent,
                hide: user.type==='boss'
            },
            {
                path: '/talent',
                text: 'Talent',
                icon: 'talent',
                title: 'Talents List',
                component: Boss,
                hide: user.type==='talent'
            }]
return(
<div>{navList.find(v=>v.path===pathname).text}</div>
)
}
```

Comment: Mayve your `pathname` is not in the list?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array.find()` returns the value of the matching array element or returns `undefined` if none is found.

Your error indicates that you're trying to access a property on `undefined`, therefore, it must NOT be finding the desired path property in your array.  Thus the `.find()` returns `undefined` and then you try to access `undefined.text` which results in the error you find.

In regular code, you'd do something like this:

```
let obj = navList.find(v=>v.path===pathname);
let text = obj ? obj.text : "";
```

Or a single line method:

```
(navList.find(v=>v.path===pathname) || {text: ""}).text
```

Personally, I'd probably just make a little function for this and call that.

```
function getTextForPath(list, path) {
    let obj = list.find(v=>v.path===pathname);
    return obj ? obj.text : "";
}
```

And, then you could use it

```
return(
    <div>{getTextForPath(navList, pathname)}</div>
)
```

If you are regularly searching your `navList` by path, then you may want a different type of data structure like perhaps a `Map` object that is indexed by path.  Then, you can just directly request a match by path without a bruteforce search every time.

Comment: Downvote retracted. Also, since he wants it in an inline way, he could do: `(navList.find(v=>v.path===pathname) || {text: ""}).text` (using a default object and the `||` operator).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - Good idea. I added that option to my answer.

Comment: make sense, but why when I do if(!navList) return null, it will still prompt the `find` error?

Comment: @JennyMok - Because `navList` is not `null`.  It's a legit object.  The issue is that `navList.find()` returns `undefined`, not that `navList` is `undefined`.